# Load Response object using json.loads()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am accessing a website that takes in text data through the URL and gives me JSON data that I can load. However, my text is really long so my current code, which uses a GET URI, will give me an HTTP 414 URI too long error.

Here is my current code (this works perfectly with small amounts of text data but not large amounts):

```
def get_json(url):
#get annotations
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    return json.loads(opener.open(url).read())

text = "random text with a lot of words"
annotations = get_json("http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

However, I am switching to the requests module because I need to use a POST URI to input a large amount of text data.

This is what my attempted code w/requests module looks like:

```
def get_annotations(text, url):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'apikey token=' + API_KEY}
    data = text

    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)
    return json.loads(response.read())

text = "random text with a lot of words"
annotations = get_json("http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

The issue is I'm not sure how to load the Response object I get from the line `response = requests....` into JSON. When I run the code, I get an "'Response' object has no attribute 'read'" Error and I couldn't figure out a way to fix it.

**UPDATE**
Error when replacing `return json.loads(response.text)`:

```
  File "annotatorConnections.py", line 17, in get_annotations
    return json.loads(response.text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: why arent you directly using json.loads(response) ?

Comment: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.You could use ``print(response.text)``.Apparently,it isn't a json.

Answer (score 1):

`requests` response object has attribute `.text`; try using:

```
return json.loads(response.text)
```

in place of:

```
return json.loads(response.read())
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response!! I tried this and I got a JSONDecodeError. I updated my code to show the error

Comment: @j.doe This suggest that what you got as response is not valid JSON. Can you `print(response.text)` or save `response.text` to file and show it?